# rhc setup - Unable to connect to the server

Tags: openshift-client-tools

I am installing the Client Tools on Windows.

I successfully completed command -> gem install rhc

Next step is --> **rhc setup**

I am using the default server, but getting below error:

```
C:\>rhc setup --debug
DEBUG: Using config file Y:/.openshift/express.conf
DEBUG: Running greeting_stage
OpenShift Client Tools (RHC) Setup Wizard

This wizard will help you upload your SSH keys, set your application namespace,
and check that other programs like Git are properly installed.
DEBUG: Running server_stage

If you have your own OpenShift server, you can specify it now. Just hit enter to

use the server for OpenShift Online: openshift.redhat.com.
Enter the server hostname: |openshift.redhat.com|

You can add more servers later using 'rhc server'.
DEBUG: Running login_stage
DEBUG: Connecting to https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api
DEBUG: Client supports API versions 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7
DEBUG: Created new httpclient
DEBUG: Request GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api

Unable to connect to the server (getaddrinfo: No such host is known.
(https://openshift.redhat.com:443)). Check that you have correctly specified
your OpenShift server 'https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api'.
```

Ruby version: 1.9.3p551

**Please note: I am behind the proxy.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After so much of RnD, I resolved the proxy issue.

set proxy before running 'rhc setup'.

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxyserverIp:port
```

Comment: After setting the proxy, I get this message: "You are not authorized to perform this operation." Any idea what is going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off all servers like Apache,XAMP and WAMP.

```
->rehit the command in cmd 'rhc setup'.
->It ask for personal server or hostname simply press ENTER for default.
->then it ask for 'openshift login'
```